# Dynamically call a macro passing parameters from shape OnAction property

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

Well, my problem is that I have created a VBA Sub that receives an excel Cell reference and 2 text values and a Variant as parameter.

```
Sub CreateButton(oCell, sLabel, sOnClickMacro, oParameters)
```

This Sub succeeds in creating a button over the oCell but I must send a parameter to the Macro what is the best way to achieve that ?

If have digged some ways that doesn't worked and also others dirty that dont make me fill confortable

---

**With the help given I managed to resolve the problem, I'm putting down here a simpler working solution for that**

```
Sub Button_Click(sText)
    MsgBox "Message: " & sText
End Sub

Sub Test_Initiallize()
    Dim oCell
    Dim oSheet
    Dim oShape

    Set oCell = Range("A1")
    Set oSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    For Each oShape In oSheet.Shapes
        oShape.Delete
    Next

    Set oShape = oSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, oCell.Left, oCell.Top,     oCell.Width, oCell.Height)

    oShape.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Click Me"
    oShape.OnAction = "'Button_Click ""Hello World""'"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can assign a string to OnAction that has the sub to call followed by its arguments (note the whole string wrapped in single quotes)

Like:

```
Shape.OnAction = "'SubToCallOnAction ""Hello World!""'"

Sub SubToCallOnAction(text As String)

    MsgBox text

End Sub
```

Numeric arguments don't need the quotes (though they will be passed in via Number -> default string conversion -> default number conversion)

So, I guess, what you are wanting to do is pass in the name of the button that was clicked:

```
Shape.OnAction = "'SubToCallOnAction """ & Shape.Name & """'"
```

More advanced and flexible usage could be something like:

```
'Set the button up like:
databaseTable = "tbl_ValidAreas"
databaseField = "Country"
Shape.OnAction = _
    "'SubToCallOnAction """ & _
    Shape.Name & """ """ & _
    databaseTable & """ """ & 
    databaseField & """'"

...
Sub SubToCallOnAction(buttonID As String, ParamArray args)

    Select Case buttonID
        Case "button1"
            'get the relevant data or whatever using the ParamArray args
            Call GetData(args(0),args(1))
        ...
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, Im trying to create dynamically a list of itens fr database that might be edited, deleted or inserted, for the first two buutons I need to get the ID on click, and Im avoiding to use the change event for all the cells, so I prefer to have Something associated in the comand button

Comment: Yeah, that worked out, thanks! I have tryed this approach before but didnt notice that the call must have single quotes. Surelly that will do the trick !

Comment: Guess what prefix you have to use if one of the parameter values is a string, and contains a single quote (character 34)? :-O

Comment: @TheBlastOne yep, strange isn't it ;). It is because two lots of double quote marks (e.g. "") inside a string resolve to a single quote mark which is why to just have a string of nothing more than a single quote mark it is the weird """" :)

Comment: @Cor_Blimley No. Or at least not sure if I understand correctly :-) Truth is: Two double quotes within a VB string resolve to one single double quote. That´s why they are there: to get the string parameter values put correctly into double quote pairs. The single quote character does not need to be escaped. So far, so clear. The question is: How would you escape a single quote within the single-quoted string? Should one be contained in one of string parameter values, the code will fail if no escaping is done.

Comment: @TheBlastOne ah I see your point - I thought you meant a single double quote. I am not aware that there is any way to escape a single quote (if there is then please let me know!). The functionality I point out in my answer is already undocumented behaviour - I think really it is *as is*. It shouldn't be used for passing in arbitrary strings. It should be used instead for passing in sufficient identifying information to locate the relevant arbitrary string in a variable stored elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

-- For people who find this page in 2016+ --

Cor_Blimey's solution doesn't work in Excel 2003.
You have to add commas instead of blanks between the arguments, like so:

```
Shape.OnAction = _
    "'SubToCallOnAction """ & _
    Shape.Name & """,""" & _
    databaseTable & """,""" & 
    databaseField & """'
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver in 2024!