# Passing arguments to sub throught button

Tags: vba, excel

I try to make dynamic buttons which call a function. This works:

```
btn.OnAction = "'DieseArbeitsmappe.Update_DB'"
```

But when I add arguments, it breaks (1st argument is a string, 2nd is the button object):

```
btn.OnAction = "'DieseArbeitsmappe.Update_DB " & Chr(34) & t.Text & Chr(34) & ", " & btn & "'"
```

It throws:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

What have I missed?

PS: Also this variant didn't work:

```
btn.OnAction = "'DieseArbeitsmappe.Update_DB """ & t.Text & """," & btn & " '"
```

Same error as above.

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/53220-calling-fuction-passing-arguments-onaction.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283786/dynamicaly-call-a-macro-passing-parameters-from-shape-onaction-property http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410115/passing-arguments-to-method-registered-with-onaction-eventvba-excel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079727/excel-vba-how-to-pass-multiple-variables-to-onaction

Comment: I've seen all of these links. The last one even brought me to the code above. But still it doesn't work.

Comment: What do the strings `t.Text` and `btn` look like?

Comment: `t.Text` holds an SQL query like "SELECT * FROM myDB" and `btn` is not a string, its the button object which is also use for `btn.OnAction`

Comment: You're trying to concatenate an `Object` (`btn` is an object) into a string. This can't be done, and will raise the 438 error you're describing.  Might I ask why you are passing the button to its own `OnAction` procedure?  Is this really necessary?

Comment: I'd like to call `btn.Delete` at the end of the procedure, so I think it is necessary.

Comment: Can't you pass the `btn.Name` and do `Shapes(btn).delete`?

Comment: In the called code, `Application.Caller` will give you the name of the button.  You can use that to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Object` of `btn` from your string as you CANNOT pass an `Object` into a string.  If you want to perform an operation or method on the `Object btn` then do that in a separate line of code within the `Sub`.

```
btn.OnAction = "'DieseArbeitsmappe.Update_DB " & Chr(34) & t.Text & Chr(34) & "'"
btn.Delete 'or Shapes(btn).Delete
```